# How to Retrieve Parent Object Custom Field in Lightning Controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a custom field Entity_Id__c on Opportunity Object. I'm building a Lightning Component and want to use from Quote Object via Lightning Action as below :

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="record" type="Object" description="The record object to be displayed"/>
    <aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Object" description="A simplified view record object to be displayed"/>
    <force:recordData aura:id="record" recordId="{!v.recordId}" targetFields ="{!v.simpleRecord}" fields="Id, Opportunity, Opportunity.Name, Opportunity.Entity_Id__c" recordUpdated="{!c.initView}"/>
</aura:component>
```

In the below Controller I'm trying to access the Entity_Id__c value but it is displayed as Null.

Controller.js

```
({
    initView : function(component, event, helper) {
        var EntityId= component.get("v.simpleRecord.Opportunity.Entity_Id__c");
    }
})
```

Is there a way we can access Parent Object Custom fields from Child. Here for example I would like to access Opportunity Custom fields in Quote Context.

Comment: Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. Please note that adding a rant about the community in your post is content which has nothing to do with what you are asking, and will be removed. It will also often lead to down votes and additional flags. Note also that creating duplicate accounts is an abuse of the system, and may incur further penalties.

Comment: It's not about the community, its about people as we come here to help each other but rather just mark it as duplicate without being kind enough. Also I earlier posted with guest account and realised later to sign in.

Comment: Those people who you are discussing and making assumptions about are the people who make up this community. You *are* talking about the community here, even if you try to phrase it differently. Regardless, it still has nothing to do with what you are asking. A `Question` post should contain only information relevant to what is being asked, just as an `Answer` post should contain only information which pertains to what was asked and how to go about resolving the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It didn't work, but I was able to solve the problem by removing Opportunity from the fields.
so the updated component looked like